# How to retrieve the secrets from AWS Secrets manager and use in buildconfig.properties in android?

Tags: android, build.gradle, aws-secrets-manager, android-buildconfig

I have added some secret keys of my app in AWS Secrets Manager. Now I need to retrieve them in buildConfig properties of android (Kotlin), through which the values of the secret keys will be generated after the build through BuildConfig.SECRET_NAME? Can anyone help ?

I have added some secret keys of my app in AWS Secrets Manager. Now I need to retrieve them in buildConfig properties of android (Kotlin), through which the values of the secret keys will be generated after the build through BuildConfig.SECRET_NAME? Can anyone help ? I didn't find any relevant information in the internet

Comment: My code :
SecretsManagerClient { region = "ap-south-1" }.use { secretsClient ->
                try{
                    val response = secretsClient.listSecrets(ListSecretsRequest {})
                    response.secretList?.forEach { secret ->
                        Log.d("SecretsManager", secret.name)
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception){
                    Log.d("SecretsManager", e.message.toString())
                }
            }

Getting this:  No identity could be resolved from the chain: CredentialsProviderChain -> EnvironmentCredentialsProvider

Comment: using kotlin or groovy?